# how to trigger an event when the motion changes its orientation in JavaFx

Tags: java, animation, javafx-8

I want to animate a node using `PathTransition`

in this example the node is a label:

```
Label l1 = new Label("Hello");
Path path = new Path();
MoveTo p1 = new MoveTo(0,0);
LineTo p2 = new LineTo(100,100);
LineTo p3 = new LineTo(100,0);
path.getElements().addAll(p1,p2,p3);

PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
pathTransition.setPath(path);
pathTransition.setNode(l1);

pathTransition.play();
```

what I want is to trigger
an event when the direction of motion changes(for example when the label starts to move from p2 to p3)

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Use two different `PathTransition`s, with `onFinished` handlers for each, and put them in a `SequentialTransition`.

Comment: Isn't there any better solution because the number of `PathTransition`s in my code could be up to 15 PTs ?

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: I will have to type 15 `OnFinished` handlers for each PT.

Comment: What do you mean by "type"? They would all be the same type.

Comment: sorry , I mean write :)  . For example : `pathTransition1.setOnFinished(...); pathTransition2.setOnFinished(...); ... ` untill `pathTransition15.setOnFinished(...); `

Comment: Umm, huh? You know that Java has loops, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an individual `PathTransition` for each portion and register an `onFinished` handler with each one. Then put all the transitions in a `SequentialTransition`:

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SequentialTransitionExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label label = new Label("Hello");

        int totalAnimationTime = 2000 ; // millis
        double[] points = {0,0, 100, 100, 100, 0} ;

        SequentialTransition animation = new SequentialTransition();
        int numPaths = points.length / 2 - 1 ;
        int time = totalAnimationTime / numPaths ;
        for (int i = 2 ; i < points.length - 1; i += 2) {
            MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(points[i-2], points[i-1]);
            LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(points[i], points[i+1]);
            Path path = new Path(moveTo, lineTo);
            PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(time), path, label);

            int p = i / 2 ;
            pathTransition.setOnFinished(e -> System.out.println("Reached point "+p));

            animation.getChildren().add(pathTransition);
        }

        StackPane root = new StackPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        animation.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```